# "Pattern syntax in expression context" error

Tags: haskell

No idea what the problem is. Following exactly the hmatrix [buildMatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Data-Packed-Matrix.html) doc:

```
Prelude Data.Packed.Matrix> let k= buildMatrix 3 4 ( (r,c) -> fromIntegral r * fromIntegral c)

<interactive>:1:26:
    Pattern syntax in expression context:
        (r, c) -> fromIntegral r * fromIntegral c
```

Comment: Missing a backslash for a lambda? `(\ (r,c) -> ...)`?

Comment: Cool that worked! And here I thought maybe there was some kind of special import to make tuples work differently.

Comment: @drozzy consider marking his reply as the answer then :)

Comment: I would - only SO makes you wait 10 minutes before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs, the markup wasn't properly escaped, it must be

```
let k = buildMatrix 3 4 (\(r,c) -> fromIntegral r * fromIntegral c)
```

The haddock markup was

```
{- | creates a Matrix of the specified size using the supplied function to
 to map the row\/column position to the value at that row\/column position.

@> buildMatrix 3 4 (\ (r,c) -> fromIntegral r * fromIntegral c)
(3><4)
 [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
 , 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
 , 0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]@

Hilbert matrix of order N:

@hilb n = buildMatrix n n (\(i,j)->1/(fromIntegral i + fromIntegral j +1))@

-}
```

The backslashes need to be escaped for them to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, now it doesn't seem to work in my code :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434808/how-to-build-matrix-of-zeros-using-hmatrix