# How to build matrix of zeros using hmatrix?

Tags: haskell

Trying to use [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix), to create a zero marix.
For some reason, when I try this on command line, it works:

```
buildMatrix 2 3 (\(r,c) -> fromIntegral 0)
```

However, when I try to do the same thing in my code:

```
type Dim = (Int, Int)

buildFull :: Matrix Double -> Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Dim -> Int
buildFull matrix basic nonbasic (m, n) = do
    -- Build mxn matrix of zeroes
    let f = buildMatrix m n (\(r,c) -> fromIntegral 0)
    m
```

it fails:

```
Pivot.hs:23:17:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (Element a0) arising from a use of `buildMatrix'
                   at Pivot.hs:23:17-27
      (Num a0) arising from a use of `fromIntegral' at Pivot.hs:23:44-55
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: buildMatrix m n (\ (r, c) -> fromIntegral 0)
    In an equation for `f':
        f = buildMatrix m n (\ (r, c) -> fromIntegral 0)
    In the expression:
      do { let f = buildMatrix m n (\ (r, c) -> ...);
           m }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Dim = (Int, Int)

buildFull :: Matrix Double -> Vector Int -> Vector Int -> Dim -> Int
buildFull matrix basic nonbasic (m, n) = do
    -- Build mxn matrix of zeroes
    let f = buildMatrix m n (\(r,c) -> fromIntegral 0)
    m
```

First, to use `do`-notation, you need a monadic return type, so that won't compile even after fixing the ambiguous element type (as I was reminded by @Carl, it would be okay here while there's only a single expression so that no `(>>=)` or `(>>)` is needed).

Concerning the element type, in the let-binding, there is no way to find out which type to use, whether `fromIntegral` should return `Double`, `Integer` or whatever. Often the type to be used can be inferred from context, by the expressions it is used in. Here, `f` is nowhere used, so there's no context. Hence in this situation, you have to specify the type by a signature, that can be

```
let f :: Matrix Double
    f = buildMatrix m n (const 0)
```

or

```
let f = buildMatrix m n (\_ -> (0 :: Double))
```

if you want the element type o be `Double`.

Comment: It's not strictly true you need a monadic result type to use do notation.  In fact, do notation introduces no constraints on the form of the expression it results, except that they be well-typed after the desugaring process.  And since that will just desugar to "let ... in ...", and not involve the >>= or >> operators in any way, that case doesn't need a monadic return type.

Comment: Hm.. i'm getting the `Illegal signature in pattern: Matrix -> Double f
        Use -XScopedTypeVariables to permit it` error if I do the first approach.

Comment: Also `let f = buildMatrix m n 0::Double` doesn't seem to work: "Couldn't match expected type `(Int, Int) -> a0'
                with actual type `Double'
    In the third argument of `buildMatrix', namely `(0 :: Double)'
    In the expression: buildMatrix m n (0 :: Double)
    In an equation for `f': f = buildMatrix m n (0 :: Double)
Failed, modules loaded: none."

Comment: @Carl Oh, right, I always forget that it's fine with single expressions of any type :(

Comment: @drozzy Oops, that must be a function, and not a number, fixed now. For the first, check the indentation. And there's no `->` between `Matrix` and `Double` there.

Comment: But I can even put a few more "let"s in there - and still I wouldn't need monadic type... Or do lets not count as expressions? Just curious...

Comment: @drozzy No, "let"s aren't expressions (`let x = y in z` is one, though), the `let f = buildMatrix ...` becomes part of the expression `let f = ... in m` after desugaring, with more "let"s, you get a nested `let f = ... in let g = ... in m`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `konst` from [Numeric.Container](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Numeric-Container.html):

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

m = konst 0 (2,3) :: Matrix Double

v = konst 7 10 :: Vector (Complex Float)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `fromIntegral 0` with `0::Double`. Otherwise the sort of matrix you want to build is underconstrained. At the prompt, extended defaulting rules are probably solving that problem for you.